# Migrating Local Users from Server 2003 x86 to Server 2008 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, users, migration

I'll try to spare the sob story, but we have an FTP server we are trying to migrate from Server 2003 x86 to Server 2008 x64.  This server has hundreds of FTP users, users that ONLY log on via FTP.

As you can guess, I'm looking for a way to migrate the users **with their passwords**.  I'm falling flat.  I did this from NT to Server 2003 with CopyPwd.  However, CopyPwd does not support x64.

Research I've done:

[SKCLONE](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://blog.sam.liddicott.com/2008/05/skclone-like-pwdump-or-copypwd-but.html&ei=DuhAUb6cEtGsqAHBr4GoAg&usg=AFQjCNH-aqceCupPuiB9pfD8UCdwBQk-qw&sig2=GVa9ZZk7CrLYvxGIGqkXyw&bvm=bv.43287494,d.aWM) - Supports x64 but does NOT support Windows 7/Server 2008 users due to the multiple security keys (not sure if that is the right terminology, but that's the gist of it).

[COPYPWD](http://www.systemtools.com/toolboard/showthread.php?810-Copypwd-with-windows-storage-server-2003-R2-64&p=3109&viewfull=1#post3109) - Found on the SystemTools forum, a link to the source to CopyPwd2(?) that uses a service to inject into LSASS.exe.  My guess is that this only works on x64 XP/Server 2003 security and not Windows 7/Server 2008 based on the reports there.

winzero ServerMigrator - Commercial utility.  Is it even legit?  Has the word 'Company' misspelled on their horizontal menu.

Has anyone successfully done this?  Used any open source or commercial utilities successfully?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ordinary FTP (not FTPS), and you have guarantee that in some period (almost) all users will logon this FTP, you should use some network sniffer to sniff out FTP passwords (because they are transmitted in plaintext)

I've googled for popular toolmaker Nir Sofer's [SniffPass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/password_sniffer.html) tool. Maybe this will work.

Or you can use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) with some filters and post-processing

So you can create accounts on your 2008R2 server using some scripting and sniffed username:password pairs